# Alpine JS change label / textbox value based on select option

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Is it possible to change a label and textfield value based on a select option in AlpineJS?

On page load, i would like the select option to be `local` and the label below to be 'Define' and the textbox value to be 'define here', but if someone chooses `remote` then the label to read 'Remote Define' and the textfield value to be 'remote define here'.

Is that possible with AlpineJS? The code i have is as follows;

```
<div>
    <label for="location">Location</label>
    <div>
        <select id="location">
            <option value="local">Local</option>
            <option value="remote">Remote</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="define">Define</label>
    <input id="define" type="text" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Alpine.js you can use `x-model` to 2-way bind an input/select (2-way because a value update in the component state/JS will update the input/select and a change to the input/select will update component state/value in JS). You can use `x-model` to deal with the `location` value updates. Note that you need a wrapping element with `x-data` on it.

Alpine.js also provides a way to set the text (`x-text`) and to bind to arbitrary attributes `x-bind`, in your case, you want to set the placeholder value so `x-bind:placeholder`.

In full:

```html
<form x-data="{ location: 'local' }">
<div>
    <label for="location">Location</label>
    <div>
        <select id="location" x-model="location">
            <option value="local">Local</option>
            <option value="remote">Remote</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="define" x-text="location === 'local' ? 'Define' : 'Remote Define'"></label>
    <input id="define" type="text" autocomplete="off" x-bind:placeholder="location === 'local' ? 'define here' : 'remote define here">
</div>
</form>
```